# Unable import django models after compiling with Cython

Tags: python, django, django-models

have compiled django app with following command
**python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace**,  which generated **models.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** file within app.

Later on running the django server, getting following error

File "/home/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in **new**
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class models.Country doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Here Country is one of the model class within models.py file

Answer (score 0):

After bit struggle found the solution ;)

It was required to add **"app_label"** in each models defined in models.py file

```
 class SomeModel(models.Model):
       some_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

       class Meta:
             app_label = 'app_name'
```